# Things that can be seen on Hoover Dam on Dec 25

Tags: las-vegas

I am planning on Visiting Hoover dam on Dec 25 . The website says [here](http://www.usbr.gov/lc/hooverdam/service/) that the visitor center is closed on Dec 25. Can anyone tell me what else can I visit if not visitor center? Or every thing will be closed on Dec 25?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the very least, you can drive around it, and walk over it.

Along the top of the dam is a walkway, spanning the width of the river it holds back. The views are pretty great, and you get a sense of size and scale.  Look over the edge down the front of the dam - it's bigger than you can fathom.

It's also possible to walk around and up a bit of the bank on the other side from the visitor center, as well as see the dam from the bridge in front of it.

The visitor center being closed means no tours, so you can't go into the depths of the dam, see the shafts and history and videos that they present. But you can read about that online. The dam itself is the sight to see.

Also, a short drive away (Between the dam and Vegas) is a great lookout over Lake Mead, the lake created by the dam.  It's definitely worth a photo or three.

Comment: D'oh! Just beat me!

Comment: Hey look, there's a [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_O%27Callaghan%E2%80%93Pat_Tillman_Memorial_Bridge) now. I bet the lack of through traffic on the dam makes pedestrian access easier.